# Passing exceptions to executable programs to stop them from execution

Tags: exception, antivirus

I heard this during a discussion that anti-viruses have this feature of stopping a program from executing by passing exceptions to it.

So how do you pass exceptions programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "pass an exception" to another program. (I have at least never heard of any such terminology.)

Most operating systems allow one process to *kill* another by for instance sending it a [*signal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29), but that's different.

Comment: Well I've heard of it from a very experienced unix guru..Most of what he said went over my head but these were the keywords I held on to.. Passing exception to a program to stop it from executing (in case of a virus)..

Maybe he was referring to something else.. :-(

Comment: Perhaps he was referring to something application specific, i.e., referring to "exceptions" as something with internal/special meaning.